# How can I retrieve compose files for stacks deployed before the current Portainer install?

Tags: docker, ubuntu, docker-compose, portainer

I made an error and wiped my Portainer data on my Ubuntu PC. After I reinstalled it, I noticed that the other stacks that were still running now showed as limited control in Portainer. Even worse, I can't view/edit their compose configs.

Is there anyway to extract compose info from a stack previously deployed before the current Portainer container?

Answer (score 2):

I've just run into this issue as well - the Portainer team as confirmed on their GitHub page that there is currently no path to import stacks created in a previous instance of Portainer. You can see their answer [here](https://github.com/portainer/portainer/issues/3262).

EDIT: I found a solution! In my case, the containers from my previous Portainer instance are still running. I found this [YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-ttZjGBkLL8) which has allowed me to export the stack configs for my containers which will make it MUCH easier to recover these stacks in my newer Portainer instance.

The tool used is [Red5d/docker-autocompose](https://github.com/Red5d/docker-autocompose)

First you need a list of all your running containers that will need their configs exported. Export your container IDs using this:

```
docker ps | awk '{print $1}'
```

You'll get an output of all of your running container IDs.

Then use red5d's docker-autocompose with your container IDs appended. This will export your config to the terminal. Use the below sample to export your container configs to a file named *autocompose.yaml*:

```
docker run --rm -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock ghcr.io/red5d/docker-autocompose 9d43bebdfac2 5188d01a764e 2e2af753c948 1cd68f808889 b11f01fe36f2 cffc0bc7dc6a 00c8aaa58db5 d77ff1739d59 59248a64b81e ccefba72bce3 02d128aa16ce 51189fb04e65 5fa8c51e5b4e 31930f131340 >> autocompose.yaml
```